# Prevent a file from getting deleted by svn cleanup

Tags: svn, ctags

I normally create a tags file (using ctags) inside the source directory of  my svn checkout. When I do svn cleanup, this file gets deleted.

Is there a way in which I can configure svn to ignore tags file, during cleanup?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- Don't misuse `svn cleanup` - it's a tool of "last resort", not needed in usual workflow.

> Finish any unfinished business in the working copy at WCPATH, and remove
>     write locks (shown as 'L' by the 'svn status' command) from the working
>     copy. Usually, **this is only necessary if a Subversion client has crashed
>     while using the working copy, leaving it in an unusable state**.

If you have to use it regularly - you have big problems somewhere

- Add generated by ctags file in repository